# Como fazer inserção em uma Árvore Binária de Busca em C

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Não estou conseguindo fazer a inserção de forma recursiva e não sei o que estou fazendo de errado..

**Preciso** seguir os seguintes protótipos:

```
struct Arvore {
    int info;
    struct Arvore *esq, *dir;
};
typedef struct Arvore Arvore;


void inserir(Arvore* a, int info);
```

Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma:

```
void inserir(Arvore *a, int info) {
    if (a == NULL) {
        a = (Arvore *) malloc(sizeof(Arvore));
        a->info = info;
        a->esq = NULL;
        a->dir = NULL;
    } else if (info < a->info) {
        inserir(a->esq, info);
    } else {
        inserir(a->dir, info);
    }
}
```

Mas não funciona, alguém sabe como posso resolver? Já pesquisei bastante e não consegui encontrar exemplos da forma que eu preciso implementar. (Com o protótipo da função sendo void)

Comment: Do jeito que está aí, além de não funcionar, vc tem um belo de um vazamento de memória, já que você não guarda nenhuma referência para a memória alocada. Como você disse que o retorno da função deve ser `void`, uma alternativa seria passar um ponteiro para ponteiro, definindo a função da seguinte forma: `void inserir(Arvore ** a, int info)`. E depois seria necessario adaptar o corpo da função.

Comment: poste um código completo :(

Answer (score 0):

Talvez ache mais simples de ler se escrever assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct st_arv
{
    int info;
    struct st_arv*      esq;
    struct st_arv*      dir;

}   Arvore;

void inserir(Arvore*,int);

int         main(void)
{
    Arvore* A = NULL;
    Arvore  outra = { 1, NULL, NULL };
    return 0;
};
```

Esse protótipo não é muito feliz. Como vai criar um primeiro nó numa árvore usando `inserir()` assim? O ponteiro não vai retornar.